# Customized folder structure for Angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am experiencing a challenge while setup my new Angular project with Angular CLI.

I would like to create a folder structure something like below:

```
-- src
    -- components
       -- app
       -- students
       -- faculty
       -- admin
       -- common
          -- search
          -- table
          -- table_row
          -- list
          -- list_item
          -- header
          -- footer
          -- side_panel
    -- services
    -- static
       -- jsons
           -- cities
           -- states
           -- time_zones
       -- imgs
       -- scss
```

If we run `ng g c some-component` command it creates new component inside `src/app/` only.

In terms of code, `app` itself is a component, then why does the Angular CLI not allow us to create another component parallel to the app component?

[image]

However, it is feasible if we create the folder's structure manually and without using CLI commands. The app also works fine.

Each application has its own size and functionality and needs some specific code design, then why impose such a limitation? Can anyone help me in understanding what the benefit of this structure is?

Comment: check the exact path.. your wrong because the CLI will start from the root folder as `src/app/feature1..`

Comment: @Aravind, we can change the root folder /file in angular-cli config. My question if it's possible to create any folder structure manually then why restrictions while using CLI commands?

Comment: @Vikramthey are using `ember-cli` blueprints that put everything below `app`, CLI only adds the dir configured as `root`.

Answer (score 3):

You can change appRoot option in `.angular-cli.json` to avoid creation of app folder:

```
"apps": [
    {
      "appRoot": ".",
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      ...
    }
  ]
```

Then you can use `ng generate` command to create component in components folder:

```
ng generate component components/common/search
```

If you want to skip creation of `src` as well then set `"root"` to `"\\"`

Comment: Thank you very much. Very helpful!

Comment: Do you have any idea how we have to configure with Angular 6 "angular.json" config? Thank you very much!

Comment: "Property appRoot is not allowed" :(

Answer (score 0):

As far as I could debug from the `@angular/cli` source, the `src` part could be set in the `apps[].root` property on the `.angular-cli.json` config file.

However, the `app/` part comes from the `ember-cli` blueprints and it seems as the opinionated path to structure Angular apps.

If you put `"root": "."`, the `ng generate component new` command will create the component in the following structure:

```
-- app
    -- new
        -- new.component.css 
        -- new.component.html
        -- new.component.spec.ts
        -- new.component.ts
```

EDIT: I have yet to solve some issues with `ng serve` that seem to be related to not using the "intended" structure, such as failing to resolve module imports and the like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is explained that the default root path of generated stuff is src/app and it's hardcoded (means you can't change it if you don't hack on ng-cli, something that's never a good idea to do).

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/3095

Answer (score -1):

I used something like that: ng g c common\some-component if you need it goes to the \common\ directory.

Comment: Try to be more specific as to how to use your solution to answer the OP's question. Maybe add some formatting to that command too! :-)